# Seperable differencial equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

If $P'= k\sqrt P$ is a model for growth in a population, and knowing that $P(o) = 1 000 000$ and $P(5) = 1 050 625$, how do I find a formula for $P(t)$?

Comment: Thanks for your response, but could you please help me get going with this integration, as I'm not used to integrating with sqrt? @Amzoti :)

Answer (score 0):

To integrate $\int \frac{dP}{\sqrt P} \, dx$ just remember the formulae:
$$(\sqrt x)' = \frac{1}{2\sqrt x}.$$
Then, from initial conditions you will be able to find the integration constant and $k$.

Comment: The answer should be P(t) = (k/2*t + 1000)^2, but how to get there?? It's Greek! @klimenkov

Comment: Try to integrate $\int \frac{dP}{\sqrt P} \, dx$.